# NPM Install says "updated 3 packages", but doesn't say which ones?

Tags: angular, npm

I just ran an npm install @angular/compiler-cli@10.0.5

I was expecting a single package to be installed. NPM reports:

```
@angular/compiler-cli@10.0.5 
updated 3 packages and audited 2595 packages in 99.636s
```

In addition to the updated compiler-cli package, how can I tell which other packages were updated?

Comment: If you use git (which you should really) - you can check the changes in your package-lock file.

Answer (score 0):

The angular cli bundle updates multiple sub packages of angular, both the common and libraries are responsible for updating zone, rxjs, and a variance of angular modules including routing.  The list is here but there are additional packages that run and install for each of those.

however in preferred order one should run

```
ng update --force --allow-dirty @angular/cli
```

then

```
ng update --force --allow-dirty @angular/common
```

the package list that is updated when you run common and cli, but there are dozens of sub depencies that also get updated - allowing dirty allows one to cross the sub dependency mismatches because they are sure to occur, often Google doesn't give us a choice on this - nor do the components that are third party libraries.

```
"@angular/animations",
"@angular/common",
"@angular/compiler",
"@angular/core",
"@angular/forms",
"@angular/platform-browser",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
"@angular/router",
"rxjs",
"tslib",
"zone.js"
```